# What is the purpose of maintaining rear in a dynamic queue?

Tags: queue

It is understood why we need to maintain a rear in static queue but why is it necessary to maintain a rear in the dynamic queue, I understand that it makes the programming easier and reduces the time complexity(b/c lesser loops are required)
but then we should maintain a rear in the singly linked list as well.

Comment: If this question isn't about a language, it should not be tagged with language tags.

Comment: Sorry for tagging the wrong language, My question isn't about linked list it is about the general structure of a dynamic queue why do we need to have a front and rear when the entire functionality can be accomplished by just a rear.

Comment: I've misread the question. The last sentence questioning singly linked list threw me off.

Comment: @Haider Imtiaz  Why did you make this conclusion "but then we should maintain a rear in the singly linked list as well. "?!

Comment: My point was if rear in a queue makes the programming easier and reduces the time complexity why not maintain it in a singly linked list as well.

Comment: @HaiderImtiaz There are two kinds of singly-linked list: one-sided list and two-sided list. Just do not use a one-sided list to simulate a queue. Instead use a two-sided singly-linked list.

Answer (score 0):

One of the operations of a queue is adding an element to the end (rear) of the queue: The enqueue operation. Maintaining a reference to the rear of the queue allows implementing the enqueue operation in constant time (although, other sources of complexity may exist depending on the type of the lower level data structure used as the basis of the queue).

> I understand that it makes the programming easier and reduces the time complexity ... but then we should maintain a rear in the singly linked list as well.

Singly linked list does not need to provide an enqueue operation, so maintaining a rear-pointer is not necessary.

However, it is possible to augment a singly linked list with a rear pointer if it is desired.

Comment: Doesn't Singly linked list provide an InsertAtEnd function which is the same thing as enqueue ?

Comment: You can provide any number of operations you like, but the "canonical" minimal singly linked list doesn't need such operation.

Answer (score 0):

> It is understood why we need to maintain a rear in static queue but
>   why is it necessary to maintain a rear in the dynamic queue

By the same reason. New elements are added to one side and old elements are pooped from other side by the definition of the notion of queue.

> ...but then we should maintain a rear in the singly linked list as well.

There is no logical relation between a queue and a singly-linked list. A queue can be implemented by any underlined container that supports the push and pop operations from opposite sides.

If you want to use a singly-linked list as the underlined container then indeed you should to use a two-sided singly-linked list to make the operations more efficient.

One-sided singly linked list is more appropriate to simulate a stack than a queue.

Comment: A dynamic queue is a sub set of a singly linked list, The enqueue and dequeue functions are the same as InsertAtEnd and DeleteAtStart (which are the functions of a singly linked list).

Comment: @HaiderImtiaz What you have written is a stupidity and nothing more.

Comment: @HaiderImtiaz What one-sided singly-list you have in nay case if you want to append new elements at the end of the list you have to find the end of the list whether the list is as you are saying static or dynamic. And this operation is evidently inefficient.

Comment: What part of my statement is stupidity, You can't understand the question,

Comment: If you can't understand the question don't bash it saying its stupidity.What you have written as an answer was already in the.

Comment: @HaiderImtiaz All parts starting  with "A dynamic queue is a sub set of a singly linked list", and ending with "The enqueue and dequeue functions are the same as InsertAtEnd and DeleteAtStart (which are the functions of a singly linked list)." because for a one-sided singly linked list only pushing front is defined. If you want to append to the end of a list new elements then you should use at least a two-sided singly-linked list as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @HaiderImtiaz Your question does not make sense and I wrote about this in my answer.

Comment: @HaiderImtiaz By the way if it is interesting to you then I did not down-vote your question though in my opinion it does not make sense.